# How to capture IActionResult in c#

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core-webapi

I have built an api caller which, for post requests, handles an input and output object:

```
public static async Task<TResponse> CallPostWebApi<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, TResponse response, string serviceUrl)
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceUrl) };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        var formData = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var result = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, formData);
        if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response;
        }

        var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(data);
    }
```

my api now returns an IActionResult with the object within it:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[Route("[Action]")]
public IActionResult MethodName(MyModel model)
  {
    try
    {
      var result =  _reqRepo....
      if (result.HasError)
      {
        return NotFound(result);
      }
        return Ok(result);
      }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
          return NotFound(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

when I call it though I don't know what to set as the return object

```
[HttpPost("[Action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitConnectionToBilling(ConnectionModel model)
{
  return await ApiCaller.CallPostWebApi(model, **???**,
            _billingApiUrl + "/MyMethod");
}
```

Comment: well, what is the type of `result` in the MethodName action? If your calling code has access to the same class libraries, it can use that same type. if not, you can just define any new class you want as long as its structure matches the JSON being returned from the service.

Comment: @ADyson it's a simple error class { hasError: bool, errorMessage: string, errors: string[] }

Comment: ok so you could easily make a simple C# class to match that structure and use that as the return type. e.g. `public class BillingResponse { public bool hasError {get; set; } ...` etc

Comment: yep. probably the best solution. Cheers